# PS4 Pro: How does Player 2 in Resident Evil 6 buy Skill Points in split-screen co-op?

Tags: ps4, resident-evil-6

Question: during split-screen co-op, we play with two player accounts signed in. During the game, both of us pick up skill point items, and after each chapter we get our ratings (and supposedly points also).

At the end of each chapter, only Player 1 appears to be able to purchase and set skills, and pressing `Option` on the controller leads into the next chapter. There seems to be no way to buy skills for Player 2, not after a chapter, and not from the main menu either.

**Is there any way to get Player 2 to purchase skills?**

Both accounts are signed in and through Prologue. If we start the game from the other player's account, then only the starting player's account gets skill points and skills, and the other player's points and (previously earned) skills are displayed as "None" in the in-game (cell phone) menu.

Side note: we beat RE6 on XBOX360 a while back and there, pressing `Start` after a chapter led to the skill screen for Player 2. On PS4, this just doesn't seem to happen.